# program works in eclipse but not after exported into a jar file

Tags: java, jar, serial-port, export, jpanel

i wrote a program that gets an input from a device and displays on a jpanel numbers according to the input
when i export my file it wouldnt show anything -as if it doesnt even start up
here is a sample code:

main:

```
public class main1 {

static CommPortIdentifier portId;
static Enumeration portList;

 public static void main(String[] args) {


        portList=CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();


        while (portList.hasMoreElements()){
            portId=(CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

            if (portId.getPortType()==CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL){

                if (portId.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("COM4")){
                    sensor sensor1= new sensor(portId,portList);
                    try {
                          Thread.sleep(3000);
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {}

                     JFrame myframe = new JFrame ("mouse controller");

                    myframe.setVisible(true);
                    myframe.setSize(400, 400);
                    MouseControlPanel mymousecontroller = new MouseControlPanel(sensor1);
                    myframe.add(mymousecontroller);

                }

            }

        }




    }
}
```

the content of the window-

```
public class MouseControlPanel extends JPanel  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

int i=0;

sensor sensor1;
String value;
public MouseControlPanel (sensor sensor1){
    this.sensor1=sensor1;
    value=sensor1.getvalue()+"";
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setFont(new Font("ariel",Font.ITALIC,50));
    g.drawString(sensor1.getvalue()+"", 100, 100);
    try {
          Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
    repaint();
}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code can be combined into one class - just put `main` into `MouseControlPanel`. Then I see the following problems:

1. missing import statements
2. nonexistent class `sensor` reference
3. relies on classes from [JavaComm](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html) - a library for detecting serial port activity that must be downloaded separately from the JDK - **you're probably missing this dependency when you try to run your .jar** - add it to your classpath.

I cannot compile your code, but I believe the following if the above is solved will work:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.Enumeration;
// CommPortIdentifier is part of JavaComm 
// see http://reprap.org/wiki/JavaComm for a description of what and how
import javax.comm.CommPortIdentifier;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MouseControlPanel extends JPanel {
    sensor sensor1; // what class is this?

    String value;

    public MouseControlPanel(sensor sensor1) {
        this.sensor1 = sensor1;
        this.value = sensor1.getvalue() + "";
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("ariel", Font.ITALIC, 50));
        g.drawString(sensor1.getvalue() + "", 100, 100);
        Thread.sleep(10);
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommPortIdentifier portId;
        Enumeration portList;

        portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
            portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

            // rewrote conditional as guard clause
            if (portId.getPortType() != CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL || !portId.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("COM4")) {
                continue;
            }

            sensor sensor1 = new sensor(portId, portList);
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            MouseControlPanel mymousecontroller = new MouseControlPanel(sensor1);
            JFrame myframe = new JFrame("mouse controller");
            myframe.setVisible(true);
            myframe.setSize(400, 400);
            myframe.add(mymousecontroller);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I should add, You'll never understand how dangerous an empty catch statement is, until you've spent hours trying to debug your code. at the very least include an e.printStackTrace().
You're probably getting error messages but you can't see them.